# Why does child edit control draw outside of tab control display area?

Tags: c, winapi

I have a tab control as child of the main window and an edit control as child of the main window. The edit control draws outside of the tab control display area. The display area is the area obtained by `GetClientRect(hTab, &rc); SendMessage(hTab, TCM_ADJUSTRECT, FALSE, (LPARAM)&rc);`Even if the edit control is child of tab control the effect is the same. I know I can create a static control as child of the tab control sized to fit the tab display area and make the edit control as child of the static control, and that would solve my problem, but I would like to make the edit control as child of tab control or main window to keep things simple. Is there any way to do that without the edit control painting outside of the tab display area?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <commctrl.h>


#pragma comment(linker, \
  "\"/manifestdependency:type='Win32' "\
  "name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' "\
  "version='6.0.0.0' "\
  "processorArchitecture='*' "\
  "publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' "\
  "language='*'\"")

#pragma comment(lib, "ComCtl32.lib")


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HWND hTab, hEdit;

    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        {
            INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icex;
            TCHAR *lpTabLabel[] = { TEXT("First"), TEXT("Second") };
            TCITEM tci;
            int i;

            icex.dwICC = ICC_TAB_CLASSES;
            icex.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
            InitCommonControlsEx(&icex);

            hTab = CreateWindowEx(0, WC_TABCONTROLW, 0, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
                0, 0, 0, 0, hwnd, 0, GetModuleHandle(0), 0);

            for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                tci.mask = TCIF_TEXT;
                tci.pszText = lpTabLabel[i];
                SendMessage(hTab, TCM_INSERTITEM, i, (LPARAM)&tci);
            }

            //hEdit = CreateWindowEx(0, WC_EDIT, TEXT("Text"), WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 
                //40, 40, 80, 40, hwnd, 0, GetModuleHandle(0), 0);
            //Now hTab is parent of hEdit
            hEdit = CreateWindowEx(0, WC_EDIT, TEXT("Text"), WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 
                40, 40, 80, 40, hTab, 0, GetModuleHandle(0), 0);
        }
        break;

    case WM_SIZE:
        SetWindowPos(hTab, 0, 0, 0, LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam), SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER);
        break;

    //This won't be sent to WndProc anymore since now hTab is parent of hEdit
    //You could subclass hTab and handle WM_CTLCOLOREDIT in there to see the same effect as in first picture
    case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT: 
        SetBkColor((HDC)wParam, GetSysColor(COLOR_DESKTOP));
        return (LRESULT)GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_DESKTOP);

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}

int WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc = {0};
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(0, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.lpszClassName = TEXT("WinClass");

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
        return 0;

    InitCommonControls();
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, TEXT("WinClass"), TEXT("Hello"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 400, 200, 400, 100, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);

    if(!hwnd)
        return 0;

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nShowCmd);

    while(GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

[image]

Second picture shows when tab is parent of edit

[image]

Comment: Why do you assume, that one control should only render inside it's sibling's client area? If you wish to set up clipping manually (for whatever reason), you should read about [Clipping Regions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183439.aspx). Don't interpret that to mean, that you have a reason to do all of this. You just need to learn how [Tab Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760550.aspx) are to be used.

Comment: I thought the tab control display area was some kind of client area where you wouldn't be able to paint outside of it

Comment: The display area is not equivalent to the client rect. For a tab control, the client rect just so happens to be the *entire* tab area, including the tabs themselves. You can verify this yourself: place the edit control at (0, 0). I'm guessing the authors of the tab control decided that the raised border would also be in the client rect. You're on your own with clipping your content to the display area, though there are a number of different ways to do so.

Comment: **Child** windows cannot render outside their parents. **Sibling** windows do not have a child/parent relationship. You are creating sibling windows. Risking to repeat myself, you need to understand how to use a Tab Control. If you don't care about learning, there's also a quick walkthrough: [How to Create a Tabbed Dialog Box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298366.aspx).

Comment: To convert between the window area and the display area for a Tab Control, use the [TabCtrl_AdjustRect macro](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760645.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable The effect is the same when tab control is parent of edit control. I have edited the code to show that

Comment: @andlabs Indeed, the client rect of the tab control is everything including the tabs, the display area, and the raised borders. In this case the client area of the tab controls is `SetWindowPos(hTab, 0, 0, 0, LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam), SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER);`, which is the same size as the client area of the main window

Comment: The recommended way to do this is to make the edit control a sibling of the tab, and position the edit control so it does not go outside the content portion of the tab control Think of a tab control as a fancy group box.