# Can you perform dialog navigation on a child window?

Tags: c, winapi

Can you perform dialog navigation with `IsDialogMessage()` on a window that contains child controls, and the window itself is a child of a tab control, and the tab control is a child of a top level window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you just use `IsDialogMessage()` with the top-level dialog, and as long as any child dialogs have the `WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT` extended window style set the dialog manager will recurse into them automatically.

Also it's generally recommended that child dialogs be overlapping **siblings** of tab controls rather than children of them (see e.g. Raymond Chen's comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31249587/why-does-child-edit-control-draw-outside-of-tab-control-display-area)).